# Generics, Polymorphism and Inheritence

Tags: c#, xml, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I am currently trying to implement an abstract Algorithm

The latter converts Data into Xml via a parser provided by the developer
Into the Expected specified type

The interface for such a converter :

```
public interface IParser<TExcpected, TSource> where TExcpected : class where TSource : class
{
    TExcpected Parse(TSource source);
}
```

This all worked fine for many various types, until the need came to specialize it a bit
and convert Key Value pairs into Metadata via the specified algorithm
Prototype:

```
public abstract class KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey, TValue, TMetadata> 
    : IParser<TMetadata, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> where TMetadata : class
{
    public abstract TMetadata Parse(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source);
}
```

I have then implemented a default class to act as a stand in for the developer's class

```
 class KeyValuePairParser<TKey,TValue>
    : KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey, TValue,KeyValuePairList<TKey,TValue>>
{
   public override KeyValuePairList<TKey,TValue> Parse(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
    {.....}
}
```

where KeyValuePairList is a generic Xml Serializable class containing a List of Metadata in some default format.

In the algorithm class, which also has these three Generic Type Parameters,
I have a Property of the Base type

```
   public KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey,TValue,TSerialized> Parser {get;set;}
```

and when trying to do this

```
 Parser = new KeyValuePairParser<TKey,TValue>();
```

the compiler claims that the types do not match

What am I missing?

Help would be appreciated!

Environment: Windows 8.1 .NET 4.5.1, C#, VS 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deferring the use of KeyValuPairList and KeyValuePairParser to an inheriting class, this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of the instance class:

```
 class KeyValuePairParser<TKey,TValue>
    : KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey, TValue,KeyValuePairList<TKey,TValue>>
```

you will see that you have only 2 type parameters: TKey and TValue

but field

```
private KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey,TValue,TSerialized> Parser {get;set;}
```

defines three type parameters: TKey, TValue and TSerialized.

You have to define this field like:

```
private KeyValuePairParserBase<TKey,TValue, KeyValuePairList<TKey,TValue>> Parser {get;set;}
```

and everything will be correct.

Comment: If I define the field like this in the Algorithm class then I would force the developers to inherit from KeyvaluePairList in order to add their own Metadata Type, which is not what I aim to do.. or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You'll force developer to use KeyValuePairList<TKey, TValue> as third type parameter (TSerialized). Otherwise, you will not be able to assign instance of new class to this field.
If you aim to use all three parameters, you have to change inheritance of KeyValuePairParser to support all three type parameters.

Comment: I ended up deferring the use of KeyValuePairList to an inheriting implementing class, this solved the issue!